# How to fetch body from imap server in Go

Tags: go, imap, fetch

I successfully fetched a list of email headers using the sample code from this url: https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap#example-Client . However, I still haven't been able to fetch the body of the emails. Can anyone show some working sample code that could fetch the body of the emails from a imap server in Golang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to get the body text now.

```
cmd, _ = c.UIDFetch(set, "RFC822.HEADER", "RFC822.TEXT")

// Process responses while the command is running
fmt.Println("\nMost recent messages:")
for cmd.InProgress() {
    // Wait for the next response (no timeout)
    c.Recv(-1)

    // Process command data
    for _, rsp = range cmd.Data {
        header := imap.AsBytes(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["RFC822.HEADER"])
        uid := imap.AsNumber((rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["UID"]))
        body := imap.AsBytes(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["RFC822.TEXT"])
        if msg, _ := mail.ReadMessage(bytes.NewReader(header)); msg != nil {
            fmt.Println("|--", msg.Header.Get("Subject"))
            fmt.Println("UID: ", uid)

            fmt.Println(string(body))
        }
    }
    cmd.Data = nil
    c.Data = nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example code you've linked to demonstrates the use of the IMAP `FETCH` command to fetch the `RFC822.HEADER` message data item for a message.  The RFC [contains a list of standard data items you can fetch from a message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5).

If you want the entire mime formatted message (both headers and body), then requesting `BODY` should do.  You can get the headers and message body separately by requesting `BODY[HEADER]` and `BODY[TEXT]` respectively.  Modifying the sample program to use one of these data items should get the data you are after.

Comment: Thanks James. Now I'm reading the RFC 3501 in order to gain more knowledge about the IMAP protocol. I'm still struggling to get the Go API work to fetch the body. Can you please show me some working code example that fetches the body of the mails. Thanks.